# how to add 8:00:00 hours to all the datetime values in a column in MS Excel sheet

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

Need a syntax for building up a formula to add 8:00:00 hours to all the datetime values in a column in MS Excel sheet.
Using Sum() Function doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method 1: New values in another column**

Assuming you have a datetime values in column A, you could calculate new values in another column with:

`=A1+TIME(8,0,0)`

or

`=A1+1/3` (because 8 hours is 1/3 of one day)

**Method 2: Update values in place**

- Put `=TIME(8,0,0)` or =1/3 in an unused cell
- Copy it to the clipboard
- Select the datetimes you want to modify
- **Edit -> Paste Special -> Add** and then Excel will add that amount of time to each cell.
- You can then delete the single cell you started with.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the paste special approach to do this in place

Answer (score 4):

If `A1` contains a datetime value and you enter the formula **`=A1+TIMEVALUE("8:00:00")`** into `B1` and `B1` is formatted as a datetime then the value displayed in `B1` will be 8 hours later than what is displayed in `A1`.

You can do something similar if you're adding time to the sum of a list of durations: **`=SUM(A1:A10)+TIMEVALUE("8:00:00")`**